# How to pass data from view to controller in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, onclick, onblur

I am developing an application in MVC in which I want to send data from view to controller and again back from controller to another view.I use the code in view,

```
<input type="text" id="ProductCode_0" name="ProductCode" style="width:10%; margin-left:0px;" onblur="AddEle()" />                
<input type="text" id='ProductName_0' name="ProductName" style="width:10%; margin-left:20px;"/>
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Create" id="create"/>
```

I use jQuery to get ProductCode-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function AddEle()
{
    var firstProductId=$('#ProductCode_0').val();
    getProductFirstDetails(firstProductId)
}

function getProductFirstDetails(firstProductId)
{
    $.ajax({
    url: "/Purchase/getProductDetails/",
    data: { Id: firstProductId },

    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result)
    {                    
    $('#ProductName_0').val(result.Name);
    }
    });            
    }
</script>
```

and in controller-

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(string ProductCode, string ProductName)
{
    if (ProductCode != "")
    {               
        Purchase oPurchase = new Purchase();

        if (ProductName != "")
        {
            oPurchase.ProductName = ProductName;
        }
        else
        {
            oPurchase.ProductName = "";
        }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("SaveData",oPurchase);
}               
 public ActionResult SaveData(Purchase oPurchase)
{   
    ViewBag.ProductCode = oPurchase.ProductName;        
    ViewBag.ProductName = oPurchase.ProductName;        
    return View();
}
public JsonResult getProductDetails(int Id)
{
    var FinalProduct = getProductEdit(Id);
    return Json(FinalProduct, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
public Purchase getProductEdit(int Id)
{
    Product oProduct = new Product();
    if (Id == 1)
    {
        oProduct.ProductCode = "234443";
        oProduct.Id = 1;
        oProduct.Name = "Product1";
         else
        {
            return oProduct;
        }
    }    
}
```

and in the view SaveData-

```
<div class="span6" >
    <div class="span4" style="margin-left:25px;">
        <label >ProductName</label>
    </div>
    <div class="span6" >        
        @ViewBag.ProductName
    </div>
</div>    
<div class="span6" >
    <div class="span4" style="margin-left:25px;">
        <label >ProductCode</label>
    </div>
    <div class="span6" >        
        @ViewBag.ProductCode
    </div>
</div>
```

Here,I use `onblur` function to fetch record from controller by `id="ProductCode_0"`.
Now my issue is that,I want to send fetched data to controller n get it back in `SaveData` view.I want to send the result to `[HttpPost]` so I use `name` in view.
But I want to prevent user to enter data in text box-

```
 <input type="text" id='ProductName_0' name="ProductName" style="width:10%; margin-left:20px;"/>
```

How to do that?
I only want to fetch data from controller and send it back to next view ie `SaveData`, without using text box for `ProductName` .Is there any way to do that using `<div>` or `<lable>`
Please help me.

Comment: What do you mean with "next view"? It is another page or some area in same page?

Comment: Its an another page named as 'SaveData'.

Comment: And when do you want to send fetched data to view `SaveData`?

Comment: I want to send it, when user click on Create button , ie `<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Create" id="create"/>`

Comment: see my answer. If you have concerns, I can give you more details

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in two ways;

**1.way**

Make second textbox hidden;

```
<input type="text" id="ProductCode_0" name="ProductCode" style="width:10%; margin-left:0px;" onblur="AddEle()" />                
<input type="hidden" id='ProductName_0' name="ProductName" style="width:10%; margin-left:20px;"/>
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Create" id="create"/>
```

**2.way**

Make second box disabled;

```
<input type="text" id="ProductCode_0" name="ProductCode" style="width:10%; margin-left:0px;" onblur="AddEle()" />                
<input type="text" id='ProductName_0' name="ProductName" style="width:10%; margin-left:20px;" disabled="disabled"/>
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Create" id="create"/>
```

However, note that, user can also change this textbox from firebug console. You need to do some validation on servier side if the form values is valid or not